# I want write a 3 words sentence, I want to be one word on line 1 and another words on line 2

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI9eu.png)I want to understand, there is any CSS3 rule to do that. to be clear my question tell you that on my website I have h1 element for example `<h1>one two three</h1>` I want h1 looks like that

```
one
two three
```

I tried to use break-word but this is not what I want.

Comment: one on line 1 two three on line 2

Comment: Try using a `<br/>` tag

Comment: Add a `<br>` tag between one and two

Comment: i dont want to use <br>

Comment: is there any specific reason for not using the semantic correct tag?

Comment: I wanted to have only h1 and if I use <br> then it cant be done it . this is the reason nothing more.

Comment: You can't do this without using `<br/>` tags

Comment: `<h1>
one <br>
two three
 </h1>` ?

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2):

There is no CSS rule that I am aware of, that can do that. But why not use HTML?

```
<h1>one<br />two<br />three<br /></h1>
```

OR:

```
<h1>MODERN<br />ART<br />GALLERY<br /></h1>
```

Comment: I wanted to have only h1 and if I use <br> then it cant be done it

Comment: If you want to do `<h1>one two three</h1>` I don't believe it can be done with CSS

Comment: <h4>MODERN ART GALLERY</h4>